# Error while loading data using sql loader. Cannot run program "sqlldr": error=13, Permission denied

Tags: java, sql-loader

I have one task in the application where it loads the data into table by using sql loader. But it is not happening and giving

> Cannot run program "sqlldr": error=13, Permission denied

. I have tried manually loading files through command prompt there it is working as expected.

Any Help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: is it on linux?

Comment: File to be loadede is in windows but java process is running on linux . We are importing file through our GUI.

Comment: As a user you have permission to execute commands but apperantly the application that you are using have no permission to directory

Comment: so how we can assign permission to application ?

Comment: run your gui application as root such as $ sudo  my_app

Comment: run this command to find path $which my_app

Answer (score 0):

You have to give read permission to the directory.

```
chmod -R 777 directory_name
```

This command will give full permission.

Runnig a gui application as root.
Firstly find your application path.

```
$ which atom   //This command give me path of my app named as atom
$ sudo /usr/bin/atom
```

Comment: But i am able to run it manually by using command prompt. So how it can be permission issue ??

Comment: is it possible for you to add your command sample in question?

Comment: sqlldr priyam/priyam@ora11g control =student.ctl